# Error 404 using wpml plugin

Tags: plugins, multisite, 404-error, plugin-wpml

I have a multi site in WordPress. I want to use the wpml plugin for the root site. The problem I encounter is that when I add a new language to the website, it does not recognize the second language version and displays the 404 error page. Sometimes a second-language version is redirected to the main language site .. Thank you for  guided me.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes setting your permalinks up and saving them helps solve this kind of problem. Settings-Permalinks-choose your default permalink structure and hit the Save.

Comment: thank you for answer my question ...But with this solution my problem was not resolved